# How to update the intent this activity will started with after recovering from background?

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity in handler `onCreate` retrieves a value from Intent and do something with it

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ....
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i.hasExtra("value")){
      String val = i.getStringExtra("value");
      doSomethingWithValue(val);
    }
}
```

Note that my activity has attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in manifest.
After executing `doSomethingWithValue` I want to clear `"value"` extra from the intent, so when next time the activity is recovering from background the intent returned but `getIntent()` should not have `"value"` extra. How can I clear this value for the next execution of `onCreate`? `setIntent` does not work here.

In other words when I press back button and then return to my app  `doSomethingWithValue(val)` is executed again but I do not need this.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Please let me know if you managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Intents can be changed or not, although the concept seems wrong to me (it was after all the Intent that started your Activity and that hasn't changed).

I propose storing the successful execution of doSomethingWithValue() in an attribute, say mSomethingDone. When the Activity is taken down by the system (not the user), onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is called. Implement that:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return mSomeThingDone;
}
```

Now retrieve the boolean in your onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
  if (data != null) {
    mSomeThingDone = (Boolean)data;
  }
}
```

And then check if you need to run your doSomethingWithValue depending on the value of mSomeThingDone.

Comment: Such approach works when I move app to background by Home button, but when I move the app to background by Back button the behavior remains wrong as before.

Comment: You should consider the Activity Lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) here. Apps are rarely destroyed when they go into the background. If they aren't destroyed, onCreate is not called when they get sent to the foreground again. I propose logging creation, resuming and starting events by adding Log statements to onCreate, onResume and onStart. Check if onCreate is called when the problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it for you, but i assume you can use `removeExtra` ?
see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#removeExtra%28java.lang.String%29